# Overshooting titration effect on K

Tags: equilibrium

> a. Explain how overshooting the titration of the aqueous layer (ie. using too large a value for the volume of thiosulfate to react with the iodine and of triiodide ion) would affect the concentrations of iodide ion, iodine and of triiodide ion, and therefore of the calculated $K$.

**My thoughts regarding this question** 
overshooting the titration will increase the concentrations of the iodide ion, iodine and triiodide ion
- According to me  a change in $K$ comes only when the **temperature** is changed.

---

> b. Explain how using too large a value for the minimum volume of thiosulfate to react with the iodine (organic) in the mineral oil layer would affect the concentrations of iodide ion, iodine and triiodide ion, and therefore of the calculated $K$

I am unsure of the answer for this one too. 
**My reasoning** 
Using too large a value for the minimum volume of thiosulfate will increase the concentrations of the iodide ion, iodine and triiodide ion and nothing will happen to $K$ again.

---

Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct that $K$ is independent of concentration. But I think you are misreading the question: it wants you to tell how *you* will miscalculate *K* with respect to the correct value if you put in the wrong concentrations in the formula, that is, if there was an overshoot in your titration.